# Oracle Database Backup Through RMAN

Tags: oracle, database-backups, rman

I'm looking for methods to backup my Oracle Database. It is hosted at a Windows server. Currently, I used Oracle SQL Developer to establish connection with the database and make changes to it. I am now considering 2 methods to backup the database.

1) Using database export function in Oracle SQL Developer

- However, the backup process seems to take forever (as the DB is around 30 GB)

2) Using RMAN to perform database backup

- I have read through the documentation from Oracle and found that the process is actually quite complicated. However, it seems to be a more efficient way and have more benefits.

I personally prefer using RMAN to perform the database backup. However, I am really new to Oracle. I haven't downloaded any Oracle Database in the local environment and I'm not sure how can I establish the connection to the existing DB like in SQL Developer through SQL*PLUS. Could someone please kindly guide me through the process?

Comment: If you just want a dump of the database, you could use `expdp` or `dbms_datapump`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I would like to do the full backup

Answer (score 1):

You need to take off your SQL Dev goggles.

At a command line:

```
c:>  rman user/password@mydb
rman> backup database plus archivelog delete all input;
rman> quit
```

That's the simplest.  You must make sure your database is in archivelog mode.

But don't forget, backup is all about recovery.  I'd very strongly urge you to create a vm on your workstation, install Oracle on that, then use that vm to practice backup and recovery. Spend some time in https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/toc.htm.  As a DBA, your Prime Directive is Do Not Lose Data. If you can't reliably backup and recover, nothing else you can do will matter.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. May I further ask about the installation process of Oracle DB? Since now I haven't install any of the Oracle DB, which version would you recommend? Also, since my purpose is to backup an existing database, should I not create another new DB during installation? And what's the procedures for me to connect to the existing DB? Sorry for too many questions here...

Comment: Version? Why would you not install the latest?  If you are backing up an existing database, why would you need to create a new one, or even install (again) Oracle at all? Yes, too many questions here.

Comment: @EdStevens Because Oracle always is a 10x extra work compared to any other DBMS - it's how their consultants make their living